# how to increase memory on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, heroku

My rails app is using too much memory:

```
Process running mem=701M(136.9%)
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Until I solve the problem, how can I increase the memory size on heroku?

Will adding more web dynos will help split the memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue with one of my clients. Sometimes digging into memory leaks can be a difficult task especially when the source of the leak could be in a third party code.

What I do is each few hours restart several dynos. I picked up non high traffic hours to do the restarts.

1. create a cron:

   ```
   namespace :utils do
     desc "Restart app by process and time table"
     task :restart => :environment do
       time_hash = {
           1 => %w[web.1 web.2 web.3],
           3 => %w[web.4 web.5 web.6],
           5 => %w[web.7 web.8 web.9],
           7 => %w[web.10 web.11 web.12],
           16 => %w[web.13 web.14 web.1],
           18 => %w[web.2 web.3 web.4],
           20 => %w[web.5 web.6 web.7],
           22 => %w[web.8 web.9 web.10],
           0 => %w[web.11 web.12 web.13 web.14],
       }
       processes = time_hash[Time.now.hour]
       processes.each {|process| restart_process(process)} if processes
     end

     def restart_process(name)
       puts "restarting process #{name}:"
       heroku = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['APP_USERNAME'], ENV['APP_PASSWORD'])
       heroku.ps_restart(ENV['APP_NAME'], :ps => name)
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use the hourly scheduler (heroku addon) to run this cron.

Comment: I just added this to my deployment:  Here i more generic implementation that works with _n_ web processes:  https://gist.github.com/2955544

Comment: you'll need to run this for APP_USERNAME, APP_PASSWORD, APP_NAME $ heroku config:add APP_USERNAME=your.email@gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Dynos have a 512M.B quotas, even if you get more dynos you will still hit the same wall. Fix your memory leaks.

> Each dyno gets 512MB of memory to operate within. Most applications
>   will fit comfortably within this allowance, and as a developer you
>   need not worry about memory at all.
>
> In some cases, your dyno may reach or exceed that 512MB amount.
>   Typically this is because of a memory leak in your application, in
>   which case you may wish to use a memory profiling tool such as Oink
>   for Ruby or Heapy for Python to track down the leak and fix it.
>
> Dynos that exceed 512MB of memory usage will display an R14 error in
>   the logs, like this:

Comment: This appears to be old information. There are several dyno types: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

Answer (score 4):

You have a hard limit of 512Mb of RAM to play with no exceptions.  This memory is on a per dyno basis.  Therefore you will not be able to deploy your application onto Heroku as it stands with it's *substantial* RAM usage.

I rarely see applications topping a couple of hundred Mb of RAM so you really need to look at the source of the problem.

With your RAM usage, even on a typical VPS you'd struggle to run more than a couple of processes at once.

Comment: This appears to be old information. There are several dyno types: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, yeah. That should do it..

"Each dyno gets 512MB of memory to operate within."

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: So do you think adding web dynos will give a temporary fix?

Comment: This appears to be old information. There are several dyno types: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

Comment: i tried to run a p5.js game on heroku optimised to require ~1Gb memory. i provided credit card no and chose 1 dyno resized to performance-m which has 2.5Gb memory instead of 0.5Gb memory of lower plans that were giving R14 out of memory errors. but heroku wouldn't let me scale and gave error `Access to performance-m and performance-l dynos is limited to customers with an established payment history`. but the only way to quickly get payment history is to buy their lame $5 Eco plan that only provides 0.5Gb of memory and doesn't run my game anyway, but i can't pay $25 for performance-m upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku updated their API , so the comments above no longer work.
I did a simpler spin off on the comments above ( in file : ***#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/schedualer.rake***) :

```
    class HerokuMaintenance
        def self.get_web_and_workers(get_ps_array)
            output = []
            get_ps_array.each do |i|
                type = fetch('process',nil)
                if type.match(/^worker\.\d+$/) or type.match(/^web\.\d+$/)
                    output << type
                end
            end
            return output
        end
        #########################################################################   
        def self.restart_all
            heroku_client.post_ps_restart(ENV['APP_NAME'])
        end
        #########################################################################   
        def self.get_ps_array(heroku_client)
            heroku_client.get_ps(ENV['APP_NAME']).body
        end
        #########################################################################

        def self.heroku_client
            Heroku::API.new( :username => ENV['APP_USERNAME'] , :password => ENV['APP_PASSWORD'])
        end
        #########################################################################   
desc "Restart app workers/web"
task :my_restart => :environment do
    HerokuMaintenance.restart_all
end
```

Following the instructions in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

 1. heroku addons:create scheduler:standard

 2. heroku run rake my_restart

 3. heroku addons:open scheduler (I set it to run every hour due to some annoying memory issues I haven't solved yet).

Comment: At the beginning I thought of doing something more complicated like the original comments (hence get_web_and_workers method) but later on I decided to simply restart everything. You can easily change get_web_and_workers method to fit your needs better and use.